# Trouble import Java Github projects to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

When I import my project to Eclipse, I can only work on it as a text file. It doesn't read it as a java project. It doesn't read nonsense words as errors and it only appears as a file system. I tried opening my project through netbeans but the same thing happened.

Comment: Does it have .project file?

Comment: Yes. The .project file looks right<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
 <name>*RealProjectName*</name>
 <comment></comment>
 <projects>
 </projects>
 <buildSpec>
  <buildCommand>
   <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
   <arguments>
   </arguments>
  </buildCommand>
 </buildSpec>
 <natures>
  <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  <nature>edu.wpi.first.wpilib.plugins.core.nature.FRCProjectNature</nature>
 </natures>
</projectDescription>

Comment: The .classpath file seems to be working as well.